# Generate a snippet from aspx page layout sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, page-layout, design-manager, snippet

I am working on a site in sharepoint 2013 and want to generate webpart snippets from some content query webparts from several page layouts. I went to the design manager in hopes of being able to do this, however there are no page layouts listed. It appears all of the page layouts I want to use were created as .aspx and don't have corresponding html files. Is it possible to use these page layouts in design manager to create snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the snippets you must have the design file (HTML file) and these snippets should be copied to only `.html` files but not `.aspx` files.

You can create a page layout from the Deisgn Manager -> Edit Page Layouts -> Create a page layout option. This comes with design file.